# Link to internal pages from include file - correct path from each page

Tags: html, hyperlink, path, include, directory

I have an include file which contains the header section for each of my pages. What I am finding difficult to grasp is the fact that my index.php file is in the root of my directory but my other pages are in the pages folder. How can I correctly link it so that when I am on the shows page for example, I can link back to the home page. You might just say do something like ../home.php but what happens when I am actually on the home page, how do I then link to the other pages because I cannot do show.php because it is not in the same directory as the index.php file. I have only one header file for all these hyperlinks remember which is why I am finding it difficult...

My directory is as follows:

**css**

**fonts**

**images**

**includes**

- header.php

**js**

**pages**

- about.php
- classes.php
- contact.php
- noticeboard.php
- shows.php

**index.php**

Below are my links on what I have achieved so far:

```
<li><a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) echo 'class="current"';?> href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'shows.php')) echo 'class="current"';?> href="shows.php">Shows</a></li>
            <li><a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'classes.php')) echo 'class="current"';?> href="classes.php">Classes</a></li>
            <li><a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'noticeboard.php')) echo 'class="current"';?> href="noticeboard.php">Notice Board</a></li>
            <li><a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'about.php')) echo 'class="current"';?> href="about.php">Our Story</a></li>
            <li><a <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'contact.php')) echo 'class="current"';?> href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you just use full path to each page using realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your .htaccess file, with this:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

And then you can go for absolute paths as follows:

/index.php
/pages/about.php

Comment: Where do I find the .htaccess file?

Comment: OK ive decided to just use the full path including http://localhost/ etc etc. Didnt need to edit any .htaccess file. When it comes to hosting it, I will just replace each link with site url's. Thanks